What does を前にした mean? Confused about this meaning
ずるい。。。恋人を前にした男って感じの接し方なのに
The character is being with their friend and thinks this. I am not sure, what does "を前にした" mean? Is to take literal as "in front of"? a way of touching of a man in front of his lover?

~を前にする (along with its variations) is a set phrase meaning to be faced with ~~ in the sense of it either being immediately in front of you physically or it being soon to happen.
It's also sometimes used as just を前に - you can read more about that here .
接する here is probably also not referring to physically touching, although it's difficult to be 100% sure without context. Consequently I'd parse this as something like:

恋人を前にした男って感じの接し方
The way a man would act in front of/interact with his lover

